# Customize Flash Player using Adobe ActionScript 3.0 : Show current time and special info

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I want is:

- I want to add current time on flash player while playing real time
  stream
- I want to open-show small info when user right click on player:
  Suppose that: "This is my tiny player...Copyrights...etc"

How can I do it easily with Adobe ActionScript 3.0?

Comment: If you had googled your question you would have seen that there is a ton of snippets doing this...

Comment: Well, instead of writing this Florent, if you give a "good"link which explain this, you will not waste your and my time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to do both with AS3.   current time is as simple as creating a new Date object.  I added some code to format the date in a normal clock kind of way.

```
now = new Date();
trace(now.hours > 12 ? (now.hours - 12) : now.hours) + ":" + (now.minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + now.minutes + (now.hours > 12 ? "pm" : "am");
```

Creating custom right-click context menu items is pretty straightforward too. Here is a tutorial on it:   http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contextmenu/

Comment: I know with trace but I was looking for context menu...And the link was about the the context menu...Thanks